# Dynamically set React Media Queries with react-responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries, react-hooks

A React component (`Viewer`) contains a dynamic list of elements (`Element`). Elements have a size depending on the current screen resolution.

The screen resolution configuration is dynamically passed to the `Viewer` component as follows:

```js
<Viewer
    elements={[{
        uid: '1',
        title: 'project 1'
    }, {
        uid: '2',
        title: 'project 2'
    }, {
        uid: '3',
        title: 'project 3'
    }, {
        uid: '4',
        title: 'project 4'
    }]}
    configurations={[
        {
            name: 'large screen',
            width: 1200,
            gridRowSize: 4
        },
        {
            name: 'tablet',
            width: 800,
            gridRowSize: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'phone',
            width: 480,
            gridRowSize: 1
        }
    ]}/>
```

The `configurations` property is dynamic and the `Viewer` component cannot make any assumption on it since it comes from a REST API. Configurations and elements are not related to each other.

I am using `react-responsive` to achieve this result as follows:

```js
import {useMediaQuery} from 'react-responsive';

export default function Viewer(props) {
    const configurations = [];

    if (props.configurations) {
        for (const [index, configuration] of props.configurations.sort((a, b) => (a.width - b.width)).entries()) {
            configurations.push({
                // props.configurations does not change between renders, so it's safe to disable the lint check
                // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
                isActive: useMediaQuery({
                    ...index > 0 && {minWidth: props.configurations[index - 1].width},
                    ...index < (props.configurations.length - 1) && {maxWidth: configuration.width}
                }),
                size: 100 / configuration.gridRowSize
            });
        }
    }

    const activeConfiguration = configurations.find(config => config.isActive);
    const size = activeConfiguration ? activeConfiguration.size : 25;

    return (
        <div className={'viewer'}>
            {
                props.elements && props.elements.map((element) => (
                    <Element
                        key={element.uid}
                        id={element.uid}
                        title={element.title}
                        size={`${size}%`}/>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is that the implementation above breaks one of the Hooks rule as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin (React relies on the order in which Hooks are called and a loop could theoretically break that order).

Without disabling the lint check, I get this error when running `eslint`:

```
React Hook "useMediaQuery" may be executed more than once. Possibly because it is called in a loop. 
React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I am currently disabling the lint error check, since `props.configurations` does not change between renders, but I am wondering whether there is a better way to configure dynamic media queries using `react-responsive`?

Comment: Since you hardcode the configuration it should not break but the linter does not know this. I'd wrap the thing in a custom hook that does something like: `const ref = useRef(0); 
  useEffect(()=>{
    ref.current++;
    if(ref.current>1){throw('Can only be called once.')}
    if(propConfigurations){...your other code}
    return configurations;
  },[propConfigurations])` If you ever mess it up then at least you'll get an error and you can put a comment there as to why you disabled the linter.

Comment: @HMR Interesting suggestion, thanks

Comment: Just realized that you can't use configurations={{key:'value'}} because the custom hook will fail. Maybe put configurations in a useMemo:  `const configurations = useMemo(()=>({key:'value'})`

Answer (score 0):

I havent used `react-responsive`, but I think I understand the issue. You have a dynamic list of props (configs) and each needs to be passed to a Hook that will define a certain property (size) to be passed to a component (Element). The problem is that all this logic shouldnt be handled in a single parent component (Viewer).

If you can use the functionality of `useMediaQuery` out of the hook that would make it cleaner. If not, you could create a component, with its own Hook, for each of those configuration elements. The code below assumes there will always be a matching query. Let me know if its not the case.

```
export const Viewer = props => {
    const { elements, configurations } = props;

    const [active_size, setActiveSize] = useState(25);

    return (
        <div className={"viewer"}>
            {configurations.map((configuration, index) => (
                <Configuration
                    key={configuration.name}
                    {...configuration}
                    index={index}
                    setActiveSize={setActiveSize}
                    configurations={configurations}
                />
            ))}
            {elements.map(({ uid, title }) => (
                <Element key={uid} id={uid} title={title} size={`${active_size}%`} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export const Configuration = props => {
    const { width, configurations, index, setActiveSize, gridRowSize } = props;

    const is_active = useMediaQuery({
        ...(index > 0 && { minWidth: configurations[index - 1].width }),
        ...(index < configurations.length - 1 && {
            maxWidth: width
        })
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (is_active) {
            setActiveSize(100 / gridRowSize);
        }
    }, [is_active]);

    return null;
};
```

Comment: Configurations are common for all items and configurations and items are not related to each other. I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori, then you only need to know which configuration is active (because there will only be one, right?) and pass its size to every Element?